# ETIMEOUT on running sample.js of VersionOne Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, versionone

I am trying to use VersionOne Javascript sdk in my project. but before doing that, I cloned the SDK from https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.JavaScript and followed the steps to build all the .coffee files. Now on running :

`node sample.js`

or even

`node sample2.js`

getting following error:

`{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }`

I checked http_proxy and everything is good. Can anyone help me out with the issue?

I am running this in Windows 7 OS under Node version 0.10.35

Answer (score 0):

It seems the request object in Node required proxy object to be set with the http proxy of my network.

`var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
...
...
var proxy = 'http:<http_proxy>';
var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxy);`

I will update the CoffeeScript file to enable it to work in http proxy environment and perform a pull request